# Removing logon name from autofill list?

Tags: gmail, login, autocomplete

Since a friend of mine used my computer to logon to her Gmail account, I am no longer logged on automatically like before, so I must type my login name and password every time.

I didn't find how to delete her logon name from the list, and go back to being logged on automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Specifying the Operating System and Browser would definitely help but I'll still give it a try.

When you're on the login field, press the down arrow key <kbd>↓</kbd>. It should open a drop-down list with the logins. Still with the down arrow key, select the desired login (your friend's) and press the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key. This will remove your friend's login from the list. If yours is the only login left, it should be selected automatically the next times.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I hadn't thought about hitting the DEL key to remove all other logon names besides mine. But after logging on/off, restarting Gmail, I'm still prompted for my password. How can I go back to having Gmail save it so that I don't have to type it every time? Google didn't return the answer :-/

Comment: FWIW, I'm using the privacy-enhanced version of Chrome, SRWare Iron 2.0.178.0 on XPSP3. The account I use for Gmail isn't mentionned in the list of saved logon/passwords in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Mac OS X Version 10.7.4. I tried the answer of anne, but unfortunately it didn't worked. I found the following from [here](http://lifehacker.com/192255/delete-firefox-auto+complete-entries). It worked for me

> Just start to type in into the form field until the grey dropdown appears, then use the cursor keys to move to the entry to be deleted and press the SHIFT key and the delete key

Answer (score 2):

**This works for Firefox / Windows/ Chrome- 
Click on the down arrow key then a dropdown list will appear.
Now select the username which you want to remove from the list and click the combination keys  "shift + delete".

Source : http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/XzwMkwmyZ9U**

Answer (score 1):

Try Shift+Delete key.

Note: When you're on the login field, press the down arrow key ↓. Then use this method.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX I had to highlight the one I wanted to delete, hit the <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, press <kbd>↓</kbd> and use <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This is an auto-complete function. Depending on the browser that you are using, you can turn it off and delete the auto-complete history.

**Internet Explorer 6:**

1. Go to Tools --> Internet Options.
2. Select the "Content" tab and click on the "AutoComplete" button.
3. Then de-select "Forms"
4. Then click on the "Clear Forms" button and that will delete the history.

**Firefox 2 and Netscape 9:**

1. Go to Tools --> Options.
2. Select the "Privacy" tab and de-select "Remember what I enter in forms and the search bar"
3. Then in the "Private Data" section, click on the "Clear Now..." button and select "Saved form and search history"
4. Click on "Clear Private Data Now" button.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrow key does not work then start with the first letter of the autofill and you will see the names in the autofill list below the sign-in spot. Then move the cursor over the name in the autofill names but do not click on it and with the name highlighted then do the shift delete. Do the same for any others

Answer (score 0):

First click on `sign in` with a different account. Once you click on that you can choose an account, and then you click `remove` and `X`. Then Click `Done`.