# Remove AutoFill in Gmail Login

Tags: email, gmail, osx-yosemite, safari, auto-form-fill

When I try to login to Gmail after clicking "sign in with a different account" via the [Login Page](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?sacu=1&scc=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&osid=1&service=mail&ss=1&ltmpl=default&rm=false#identifier) to use one of my non-regular emails, I get Suggestions. The suggestions are mostly times I messed up and pressed Enter before the autofill, such as

fir

first.

first.las

first.last@do

first.last@domain.net

How do I remove these extra Logins? I already looked at [superuser/autofill](https://superuser.com/questions/59312/removing-logon-name-from-autofill-list), but I use Safari on a Mac running OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite).